# How to set background image to textfield in Swift

Tags: swift2

I want to set background image to the textfield. The image is too large so only few part of it is looking in background. I need solution so that the whole image should set in background of the textfield. I used following code, but it not working well.

```
textField.background  = UIImage(named: "textFeildBackground.png")!
```

I also tried the following code.. but it still not fulfil the need.

```
let myImage = UIImage(named: "textFeildBackground.png")
let myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.textField.frame.width - 50 , height: self.textField.frame.height))
myImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
myImageView.image = myImage
textField.addSubview(myImageView)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to do it via the storyboard and the attributes inspector.

Add you image `"textFeildBackground.png"`to your `Assets.xcassets` as is shown below; in example I have chosen to name `image` as reference for my image.

[image]

Select your `UITextField` in your storyboard, and open the attributes inspector. From here, find the `Background` field and choose `image` from the drop-down menu (in your case, `image` will be whatever reference name you chose for the image set in the `Assets.xcassets` folder). Also in the attributes inspector, preferably set the border style to .None (as shown in example below).

[image]

When you run your app, the image should be fitted to your text field background.

Comment: Actually I have the image which have half border,  when I set that image to background of textfield  in story board it is looking fine but at runtime it not showing just underline to that textfeild not half border to textfield. Please give me solution on that

Comment: I don't know if I quite understand what you mean by your half border image. Before that: Have you removed the code you mentioned in your question from your source? With the method described above, you shouldn't need to do any additional "manual" code editing of the background image. Also, make sure that you've set the border style of the text field to none (leftmost, as performed in 2nd gif above). After double-checking these steps, is the background image still not as intended at runtime?

Comment: yes , I have removed all code and followed the steps which you have mentioned above, but runtime it is not looking as look in storyboard